# Making multiple request using jsonp and same callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

Hey I want to achieve being able to call multiple request using jsonp and the same callback function. The way I am doing it currently is setting intervals between each call, which is horrid in that if I wanted to make 10 request calls, it would take 10 seconds to retrieve all the data. If I shorten the time then it returns a parseerror.

I was wondering if there was any way of being able to make these request almost simultaneously.

Here is my code for the ajax request call: (the relevant code)

```
  var parameterMap = OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters);
  console.log("3");
  $.ajax({
    'url' : message.action,
    'data' : parameterMap,
    'dataType' : 'jsonp',
    'async' : 'true',
    'jsonpCallback' : 'cb',
    'cache': true
  })
  .done(function(data, textStatus) {
    console.log("Coming in");
    var mapIndex = yelpRequestCounter.toString();
    console.log("Map Index being set is: " + mapIndex);
    yelpResults = yelpResults.set(mapIndex, data.businesses);
        console.log("4");
        console.log("Success promise: " + yelpRequestCounter);
        console.log("Ending");
        if(yelpRequestCounter == 9){
          findPriorityResuts(subPoints);
          yelpRequestCounter = 0;
        }
        // console.log('success[' + JSON.stringify(data) + '], status[' + textStatus + ']'); //', jqXHR[' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + ']\n');
    }
  )
  .fail(function(data) {
    console.log("Failed")
        // console.log('error[' + errorThrown + '], status[' + textStatus + '], jqXHR[' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + ']');
    }
  );
```

}

My call back function is just an empty method because I thought if i had retrieved all my data in the promise, then I would not have an error.(which I was wrong).

Here is the function that makes the request:

```
var generateBusiness = function(term, subPointResults){
  console.log("generateBusiness is being called");

  var waitForCB = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("CB Counter = " + yelpRequestCounter);
    latlngString = subPointResults[yelpRequestCounter].lat().toString() + "," + subPointResults[yelpRequestCounter].lng().toString();
    yelpSearch(term, latlngString,subPointResults);
    yelpRequestCounter++;
    console.log(yelpRequestCounter + "---------------------");

    if(yelpRequestCounter === subPointResults.length){
      console.log("It stops!");
      clearInterval(waitForCB);
    }

  },1000);
}
```

If I shortened the time or was in a place with bad connectivity then this will almost not work.

Thanks for your time and help ! :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem can be solved by using the Jquery's $when().then() functions.

Here is a sample template of one of the ways you can do it.

```
 $.when(ajax1(), ajax2().., ajaxN()).then(function(response1, response2,.., responseN){

});

function ajax1() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "url",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    ...
});
}

function ajax2() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "url",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    ...
});
}
...
```

Edit: Alternatively if you want to use a loop to make all the ajax requests in lieu of writing multiple functions, you can use the Function.prototype.apply property. e.g. `$.when.apply($, my_array);`

Here is a sample template.

```
var results = []; // results of all the ajax calls

function getPromises() {
    var promises = [];

    var i = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        var count = i;

        promises.push(
            $.post('/echo/html/', {
                html: "<p>Task #" + count + " complete.",
                delay: count
            }).success(function(data) {

                results.push(data)
            }));
    }

    return promises;
}

$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {


        var promises = getPromises();

        $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() {

            $("div").append("<p>All done!</p>" + results[0] + " | " + results[1]);
        });

    })
})
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#">Make Ajax Requests!</a>
 <div></div>
```

Comment: would you mind elaborating? To my understanding, do i need to make X amount of ajax request for however much i want ? and is the response the data that I would retrieve from requestN ?

Comment: Hi @lobcity42, the callback inside of the the 'then()' will execute only after all the ajax calls made in the when() are complete(done). Thus, you don't have to separately wait for each ajax response. The response1 , response2 ..etc are the responseData you get back from the Ajax calls.

Comment: Also, you can make as many ajax calls as you need within the $.when() function.

Comment: hey @piyush, so then would that mean that I would need to create multiple ajax request functions? would it work if I wanted to make multiple requests on a single ajax request function?

Comment: to elaborate. if i were to encapsulate the when, then functions inside a for loop and repeatedly call my ajax request, then would each ajax request be successfully be chained to the correct request?

Comment: Hi @lobcity42, please check my edited answer. See if it helps.

Comment: hey @piyush  would you mind helping me out one last time. Im afraid that the when then functions solves my issue of needing a delay per request. As again i want to point out that im working with JSONP data types. 
would you mind reviewing my code to see if theres an obvious issue
https://jsfiddle.net/ottnpw24/ 
I might have implemented incorrectly but im getting the error of: error[Error: cb was not called], status[parsererror], jqXHR[{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"}]